# How to memoizes this recurrence for minimum coin problem?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I tried memoizing the value of 'x', but it gives wrong answer.

Uncommenting the commented part will give wrong answer.

```cpp
//vi dp(1000001,-1);

int f(int x,int cnt,const vi &v){
    if(x<0)return INT_MAX;
    if(x==0)return cnt;
    //if(dp[x]!=-1)return dp[x];
    int ans=INT_MAX;
    for(const int &i:v){
        ans=min(ans,f(x-i,cnt+1,v));
    }
    //dp[x]=ans;
    return ans;
}
```

Without memoization, this is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has 2 states and you are storing value for just one state. Suppose you want the value of f(2,2,v). Your dp[2] array can contain any values among f(2,x,v) where x can be any value of "cnt".

Comment: Yes, I tried that but the value of 'x' and 'cnt' can go upto 10^6 and 100 respectively (so 10^8 in total). This is giving TLE or segmentation fault.

Comment: If you observe carefully you don't need to use 'cnt' as a state.. I am assuming the array size is <= 100. Dropping 'cnt' will give u a time complexity of O(x * arraySize) and memory complexity O(x).

Comment: How do I eliminate 'cnt'? Is there any general rule I can follow?

Comment: You have to minimize the parameter 'cnt'. So instead of passing it as a parameter you can just add it with the function.

`f(int x,int cnt,const vi &v)` will be `f(int x,const vi &v)` ,

`if(x==0) return cnt;` will be `if(x==0)return 0;` ,

`ans=min(ans,f(x-i,cnt+1,v));` will be `ans=min(ans,f(x-i,,v) + 1);` ,